# If the calculated grand total is a negative value, set it to zero instead.The user should be alerted that an error has occurred. use the prompt box

Tags: javascript, html

i cant get 0 on grand total when i enter the amount all in positive values then change the unit price all to negative values. but it works when i dont enter the positive value and only entering negative values into it. HELP ME GET THAT 0 PLEASE----------------------------------

This is my html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Book Ordering System</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="book-order.css">
 </head>
 <h1>Book Ordering System</h1>
 <body class="background">
     <script src="book-order.js"></script>
     <table id="head">
         <tr>
             <th>No.</th>
             <th>Book Title</th>
             <th>Author</th>
             <th>Category</th>
             <th>Unit Price</th>
             <th>Quantity</th>
             <th>Total</th>
         </tr>
         <tr class="hover middle">
             <td>1</td>
             <td><input type = "text"></td>
             <td><input type ="text"class="center"></td>
             <td><select name = "type">
                <option value = "Choose"disabled>Choose a Category...</option>
                <option value = "Business">Business</option>
                <option value = "Fiction">Fiction</option>
                <option value = "Mathematics">Mathematics</option>
                <option value = "Technology">Technology</option>
                </select></td>
                <td><input type = "number" name = "unit price" id="book1_price" placeholder = "0.00"></td>
                <td><input type ="number" name = "Quantity" id="book1_quan" placeholder = "0"></td>
                <td><input type ="number"   name = "theProduct" id ="book1_total" class = "total" value = "0.00" disabled></td>
         </tr>    
         <tr class="hover middle">
             <td>2</td>
             <td><input type = "text" class="center"></td>
             <td><input type = "text" class="center"></td>
             <td><select name = "type">
                <option value = "Choose"disabled>Choose a Category...</option>
                <option value = "Business">Business</option>
                <option value = "Fiction">Fiction</option>
                <option value = "Mathematics">Mathematics</option>
                <option value = "Technology">Technology</option>
                </select></td>
            <td><input type = "number" name = "unit price"  id="book2_price" placeholder = "0.00" ></td>
            <td><input type ="number" name = "Quantity" id= "book2_quan" placeholder = "0"></td>
            <td><input type ="number" name = "total" id="book2_total" class = "total"value = "0.00" disabled></td>
         </tr>    
         <tr class="hover middle">
            <td>3</td>
            <td><input type = "text" class="center"></td>
            <td><input type = "text" class="center"></td>
            <td><select name = "type">
                <option value = "Choose"disabled>Choose a Category...</option>
                <option value = "Business">Business</option>
                <option value = "Fiction">Fiction</option>
                <option value = "Mathematics">Mathematics</option>
                <option value = "Technology">Technology</option>
                </select></td>
            <td><input type = "numnber" name = "unit price"  id="book3_price" placeholder = "0.00"></td>
            <td><input type ="number" name = "Quantity" id="book3_quan" placeholder = "0"></td>
            <td><input type ="number" name = "total" id="book3_total" class = "total"value = "0.00" disabled></td>
        </tr>            
        <tr class="hover middle">
            <td>4</td>
            <td><input type = "text" class="center"></td>
            <td><input type = "text" class="center"></td>
            <td><select name = "type">
                <option value = "Choose"disabled>Choose a Category...</option>
                <option value = "Business">Business</option>
                <option value = "Fiction">Fiction</option>
                <option value = "Mathematics">Mathematics</option>
                <option value = "Technology">Technology</option>
                </select></td>
            <td><input type = "number" name = "unit price" id="book4_price" placeholder = "0.00"></td>
            <td><input type ="number" name = "Quantity" id="book4_quan" placeholder = "0"></td>
            <td><input type ="number" name = "total"  id="book4_total" class = "total"value = "0.00" disabled></td>
        </tr>                  
        <tr class="hover middle">
            <td>5</td>
            <td><input type = "text" class="center"></td>
            <td><input type = "text" class="center"></td>
            <td><select name = "type">
                <option value = "Choose"disabled>Choose a Category...</option>
                <option value = "Business">Business</option>
                <option value = "Fiction">Fiction</option>
                <option value = "Mathematics">Mathematics</option>
                <option value = "Technology">Technology</option>
                </select></td>
            <td><input type = "number" name = "unit price" id="book5_price" placeholder = "0.00" min="0"></td>
            <td><input type ="number" name = "Quantity" id="book5_quan"placeholder = "0"></td>
            <td><input type ="number" name = "total" id="book5_total" class = "total"value = "0.00" disabled></td>
        </tr>            
         <tr id="footer">
             <td colspan = "5"><input type = "Submit" id = "click" onclick = "calculateTotal()" value = "Calculated Grand Total Price" style="font-size: 18px;"></td>
             <td colspan = "2"><input type = "number" name = "total" class= "total" id="grandtotal" value = "0.00" style = "width: 300px; height: 40px; font-weight: bolder; font-size: larger;"disabled/>
         </tr>   
     </table>
     <br/>
     <input style="display:none" type="button" id ="button" class="btn" value="Discount 10%" onclick="newGrandTotal()">
     <br/>
     <br/>
     <a href= "Index.html">Go back to home</a>
     <br/>
 </body>
```

this is my javascript:

function calculateTotal() {

```
const NumberOfBooks = 5;

for (let i = 1; i<= NumberOfBooks; ++i) {
document.getElementById("book" + i + "_price").value = (document.getElementById("book" + i + "_price").value / 1).toFixed(2);
    }
// row 1
var price1 = document.getElementById("book1_price").value;
var quan1 = document.getElementById("book1_quan").value;
var total1 = document.getElementById("book1_total");
total1.value = (price1 * quan1).toFixed(2);
// row 2 
var price2 = document.getElementById("book2_price").value;
var quan2 = document.getElementById("book2_quan").value;
var total2 = document.getElementById("book2_total");
total2.value = (price2 * quan2).toFixed(2);

// row 3 
var price3 = document.getElementById("book3_price").value;
var quan3 = document.getElementById("book3_quan").value;
var total3 = document.getElementById("book3_total");
total3.value = (price3 * quan3).toFixed(2);

// row 4 
var price4 = document.getElementById("book4_price").value;
var quan4 = document.getElementById("book4_quan").value;
var total4 = document.getElementById("book4_total");
total4.value = (price4 * quan4).toFixed(2);

// row 5 
var price5 = document.getElementById("book5_price").value;
var quan5 = document.getElementById("book5_quan").value;
var total5 = document.getElementById("book5_total");
total5.value = (price5 * quan5).toFixed(2);
    
// grandtotal
var grandtotal = document.getElementById("grandtotal");

fulltotal = parseFloat(total1.value) + parseFloat(total2.value) + parseFloat(total3.value) 
            + parseFloat(total4.value) + parseFloat(total5.value);
            
//error
if(fulltotal < 0) {
    alert("An error has occurred: Please enter a positive value.");
    document.getElementById("grandtotal")[0].value = 0;
    
    fulltotal = 0
   
}
grandtotal.value = fulltotal.toFixed(2);
 checkGrandTotal();
}
function checkGrandTotal(){

    var value = document.getElementById("grandtotal").value;
    if(value > 250){
    document.getElementById("button").style.display ="block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('button').style.display ="none";
    
    }
}
    function newGrandTotal(){
    var total = document.getElementById("grandtotal").value;
    
    var newtotal = total-(total / 10);
    alert("New grand total is :" + newtotal.toFixed(2));
}
```

Comment: Remove `[0]` from `document.getElementById("grandtotal")[0].value = 0;`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly know what you mean but I think you need to make an `if()` statement.

Like this:

```
if(newtotal < 0){
newtotal = 0;
}
```

Atleast i think you just don't want to go negative on the total. So when the newtotal is negative make it 0. If im getting you wrong let me know!

Comment: so first,  you enter all the value inside unit price and quantity then click the calculate grand total price. Next, add negative signs on all the value in unit price then click calculate grand total price. Ya then the grand total input box should be zero. but in my code is not zero

Answer (score 0):

I comment this line `document.getElementById("grandtotal")[0].value = 0;` and it works.

You don't need to assign a value to `grandtotal` here because you only assign the `grandtotal` in the end of the function based on the value of the `fulltotal`.

```js
function calculateTotal() {
  const NumberOfBooks = 5;

  for (let i = 1; i <= NumberOfBooks; ++i) {
    document.getElementById("book" + i + "_price").value = (
      document.getElementById("book" + i + "_price").value / 1
    ).toFixed(2);
  }
  // row 1
  var price1 = document.getElementById("book1_price").value;
  var quan1 = document.getElementById("book1_quan").value;
  var total1 = document.getElementById("book1_total");
  total1.value = (price1 * quan1).toFixed(2);
  // row 2
  var price2 = document.getElementById("book2_price").value;
  var quan2 = document.getElementById("book2_quan").value;
  var total2 = document.getElementById("book2_total");
  total2.value = (price2 * quan2).toFixed(2);

  // row 3
  var price3 = document.getElementById("book3_price").value;
  var quan3 = document.getElementById("book3_quan").value;
  var total3 = document.getElementById("book3_total");
  total3.value = (price3 * quan3).toFixed(2);

  // row 4
  var price4 = document.getElementById("book4_price").value;
  var quan4 = document.getElementById("book4_quan").value;
  var total4 = document.getElementById("book4_total");
  total4.value = (price4 * quan4).toFixed(2);

  // row 5
  var price5 = document.getElementById("book5_price").value;
  var quan5 = document.getElementById("book5_quan").value;
  var total5 = document.getElementById("book5_total");
  total5.value = (price5 * quan5).toFixed(2);

  // grandtotal
  var grandtotal = document.getElementById("grandtotal");

  fulltotal =
    parseFloat(total1.value) +
    parseFloat(total2.value) +
    parseFloat(total3.value) +
    parseFloat(total4.value) +
    parseFloat(total5.value);

  //error
  if (fulltotal < 0) {
    alert("An error has occurred: Please enter a positive value.");
    // document.getElementById("grandtotal")[0].value = 0;

    fulltotal = 0;
  }

  grandtotal.value = fulltotal.toFixed(2);
  checkGrandTotal();
}
function checkGrandTotal() {
  var value = document.getElementById("grandtotal").value;
  if (value > 250) {
    document.getElementById("button").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("button").style.display = "none";
  }
}
function newGrandTotal() {
  var total = document.getElementById("grandtotal").value;

  var newtotal = total - total / 10;
  alert("New grand total is :" + newtotal.toFixed(2));
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Book Ordering System</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="book-order.css" />
  </head>
  <h1>Book Ordering System</h1>
  <body class="background">
    <script src="book-order.js"></script>
    <table id="head">
      <tr>
        <th>No.</th>
        <th>Book Title</th>
        <th>Author</th>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>Unit Price</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Total</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="hover middle">
        <td>1</td>
        <td><input type="text" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="center" /></td>
        <td>
          <select name="type">
            <option value="Choose" disabled>Choose a Category...</option>
            <option value="Business">Business</option>
            <option value="Fiction">Fiction</option>
            <option value="Mathematics">Mathematics</option>
            <option value="Technology">Technology</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input
            type="number"
            name="unit price"
            id="book1_price"
            placeholder="0.00"
          />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input
            type="number"
            name="Quantity"
            id="book1_quan"
            placeholder="0"
          />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input
            type="number"
            name="theProduct"
            id="book1_total"
            class="total"
            value="0.00"
            disabled
          />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="hover middle">
        <td>2</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="center" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="center" /></td>
        <td>
          <select name="type">
            <option value="Choose" disabled>Choose a Category...</option>
            <option value="Business">Business</option>
            <option value="Fiction">Fiction</option>
            <option value="Mathematics">Mathematics</option>
            <option value="Technology">Technology</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input
            type="number"
            name="unit price"
            id="book2_price"
            placeholder="0.00"
          />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input
            type="number"
            name="Quantity"
            id="book2_quan"
            placeholder="0"
          />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input
            type="number"
            name="total"
            id="book2_total"
            class="total"
            value="0.00"
            disabled
          />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="hover middle">
        <td>3</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="center" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="center" /></td>
        <td>
          <select name="type">
            <option value="Choose" disabled>Choose a Category...</option>
            <option value="Business">Business</option>
            <option value="Fiction">Fiction</option>
            <option value="Mathematics">Mathematics</option>
            <option value="Technology">Technology</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input
            type="numnber"
            name="unit price"
            id="book3_price"
            placeholder="0.00"
          />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input
            type="number"
            name="Quantity"
            id="book3_quan"
            placeholder="0"
          />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input
            type="number"
            name="total"
            id="book3_total"
            class="total"
            value="0.00"
            disabled
          />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="hover middle">
        <td>4</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="center" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="center" /></td>
        <td>
          <select name="type">
            <option value="Choose" disabled>Choose a Category...</option>
            <option value="Business">Business</option>
            <option value="Fiction">Fiction</option>
            <option value="Mathematics">Mathematics</option>
            <option value="Technology">Technology</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input
            type="number"
            name="unit price"
            id="book4_price"
            placeholder="0.00"
          />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input
            type="number"
            name="Quantity"
            id="book4_quan"
            placeholder="0"
          />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input
            type="number"
            name="total"
            id="book4_total"
            class="total"
            value="0.00"
            disabled
          />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="hover middle">
        <td>5</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="center" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="center" /></td>
        <td>
          <select name="type">
            <option value="Choose" disabled>Choose a Category...</option>
            <option value="Business">Business</option>
            <option value="Fiction">Fiction</option>
            <option value="Mathematics">Mathematics</option>
            <option value="Technology">Technology</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input
            type="number"
            name="unit price"
            id="book5_price"
            placeholder="0.00"
            min="0"
          />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input
            type="number"
            name="Quantity"
            id="book5_quan"
            placeholder="0"
          />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input
            type="number"
            name="total"
            id="book5_total"
            class="total"
            value="0.00"
            disabled
          />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="footer">
        <td colspan="5">
          <input
            type="Submit"
            id="click"
            onclick="calculateTotal()"
            value="Calculated Grand Total Price"
            style="font-size: 18px"
          />
        </td>
        <td colspan="2">
          <input
            type="number"
            name="total"
            class="total"
            id="grandtotal"
            value="0.00"
            style="
              width: 300px;
              height: 40px;
              font-weight: bolder;
              font-size: larger;
            "
            disabled
          />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br />
    <input
      style="display: none"
      type="button"
      id="button"
      class="btn"
      value="Discount 10%"
      onclick="newGrandTotal()"
    />
    <br />
    <br />
    <a href="Index.html">Go back to home</a>
    <br />
  </body>
  <script src="test.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could address the right element withou using an index.

Beside this, you could take a function for getting the products of all rows to prevent writing more code than necessary to get a row total.

Finally exit the function on error.

(In a next step, I would suggest to duplicate the data as array and use this values instead if retrieving data from input. Onyl changes of input should change the array for final total with discount.)

```js
function calculateTotal() {
    function calculateRow(row) {
        const
            price = document.getElementById(`${row}_price`),
            quantity = document.getElementById(`${row}_quan`),
            total = document.getElementById(`${row}_total`),
            product = price.value * quantity.value;


        price.value = (+price.value).toFixed(2);
        total.value = product.toFixed(2);
        return product;
    }

    const NumberOfBooks = 5;
    let total = 0;

    for (let i = 1; i <= NumberOfBooks; ++i) {
        total += calculateRow(`book${i}`);
    }

    // grandtotal
    var grandtotal = document.getElementById("grandtotal");

    if (total < 0) {
        alert("An error has occurred: Please enter a positive value.");
        grandtotal.value = '0.00';
        return;
    }
    grandtotal.value = total.toFixed(2);
    checkGrandTotal();
}

function checkGrandTotal() {

  var value = document.getElementById("grandtotal").value;
  if (value > 250) {
    document.getElementById("button").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('button').style.display = "none";

  }
}

function newGrandTotal() {
  var total = document.getElementById("grandtotal").value;

  var newtotal = total - (total / 10);
  alert("New grand total is :" + newtotal.toFixed(2));
}
```

```html
<h1>Book Ordering System</h1>

<body class="background">
  <script src="book-order.js"></script>
  <table id="head">
    <tr>
      <th>No.</th>
      <th>Book Title</th>
      <th>Author</th>
      <th>Category</th>
      <th>Unit Price</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hover middle">
      <td>1</td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="center"></td>
      <td>
        <select name="type">
          <option value="Choose" disabled>Choose a Category...</option>
          <option value="Business">Business</option>
          <option value="Fiction">Fiction</option>
          <option value="Mathematics">Mathematics</option>
          <option value="Technology">Technology</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td><input type="number" name="unit price" id="book1_price" placeholder="0.00"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="Quantity" id="book1_quan" placeholder="0"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="theProduct" id="book1_total" class="total" value="0.00" disabled></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hover middle">
      <td>2</td>
      <td><input type="text" class="center"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="center"></td>
      <td>
        <select name="type">
          <option value="Choose" disabled>Choose a Category...</option>
          <option value="Business">Business</option>
          <option value="Fiction">Fiction</option>
          <option value="Mathematics">Mathematics</option>
          <option value="Technology">Technology</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td><input type="number" name="unit price" id="book2_price" placeholder="0.00"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="Quantity" id="book2_quan" placeholder="0"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="total" id="book2_total" class="total" value="0.00" disabled></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hover middle">
      <td>3</td>
      <td><input type="text" class="center"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="center"></td>
      <td>
        <select name="type">
          <option value="Choose" disabled>Choose a Category...</option>
          <option value="Business">Business</option>
          <option value="Fiction">Fiction</option>
          <option value="Mathematics">Mathematics</option>
          <option value="Technology">Technology</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td><input type="numnber" name="unit price" id="book3_price" placeholder="0.00"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="Quantity" id="book3_quan" placeholder="0"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="total" id="book3_total" class="total" value="0.00" disabled></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hover middle">
      <td>4</td>
      <td><input type="text" class="center"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="center"></td>
      <td>
        <select name="type">
          <option value="Choose" disabled>Choose a Category...</option>
          <option value="Business">Business</option>
          <option value="Fiction">Fiction</option>
          <option value="Mathematics">Mathematics</option>
          <option value="Technology">Technology</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td><input type="number" name="unit price" id="book4_price" placeholder="0.00"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="Quantity" id="book4_quan" placeholder="0"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="total" id="book4_total" class="total" value="0.00" disabled></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hover middle">
      <td>5</td>
      <td><input type="text" class="center"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="center"></td>
      <td>
        <select name="type">
          <option value="Choose" disabled>Choose a Category...</option>
          <option value="Business">Business</option>
          <option value="Fiction">Fiction</option>
          <option value="Mathematics">Mathematics</option>
          <option value="Technology">Technology</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td><input type="number" name="unit price" id="book5_price" placeholder="0.00" min="0"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="Quantity" id="book5_quan" placeholder="0"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="total" id="book5_total" class="total" value="0.00" disabled></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="footer">
      <td colspan="5"><input type="Submit" id="click" onclick="calculateTotal()" value="Calculated Grand Total Price" style="font-size: 18px;"></td>
      <td colspan="2"><input type="number" name="total" class="total" id="grandtotal" value="0.00" style="width: 300px; height: 40px; font-weight: bolder; font-size: larger;" disabled/>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br/>
  <input style="display:none" type="button" id="button" class="btn" value="Discount 10%" onclick="newGrandTotal()">
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <a href="Index.html">Go back to home</a>
```